# how to remove duplicate elements whem the dict key value is a list

Tags: json, list, ansible, jinja2

I have below output, how to remove duplicate ip's from 'source' and 'dest' key value list and print as shown in desired output section.
tried `{{output.msg|unique}}` that didn't work

```
      {[ {
            "Name": "A",
            "source": [
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23",
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23"
            ],
            "dest": [
                "10.10.10.20/32",
                "10.10.10.20/32",
                "10.10.10.20/32",
                "10.10.10.20/32",
                "10.10.10.21/32",
                "10.10.10.21/32",
                "10.10.10.21/32",
                "10.10.10.21/32"
            ],
        },
        {
            "Name": "B",
            "source": [
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23",
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23"
            ],
            "dest": [
                "20.20.20.233/32",
                "20.20.20.233/32",
                "20.20.20.233/32",
                "20.20.20.233/32",
                "20.20.20.234/32",
                "20.20.20.234/32",
                "20.20.20.234/32",
                "20.20.20.234/32"
            ],
        },
        {
            "Name": "C",
            "source": [
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23"
            ],
            "dest": [
                "30.30.30.78/32",
                "30.30.30.78/32",
                "30.30.30.78/32",
                "30.30.30.78/32"
            ],
        }
        ]}
```

desired output:

```
      {[ {
            "Name": "A",
            "source": [
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23",

            ],
            "dest": [
                "10.10.10.20/32",
                "10.10.10.21/32",
            ],
        },
        {
            "Name": "B",
            "source": [
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23",
            ],
            "dest": [
                "20.20.20.233/32",
            ],
        },
        {
            "Name": "C",
            "source": [
                "1.1.1.0/24",
                "2.2.2.0/23",
                "3.3.3.0/24",
                "4.4.4.0/23"
            ],
            "dest": [
                "30.30.30.78/32",
            ],
        }
        ]}
```

Comment: You might want to [edit] the question and make it [mre] with the focus on *minimal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the data a bit, e.g.

```yaml
  output:
    - Name: A
      source: [a, b, c, a, b, c]
      dest: [x, y, z, x, y, z]
    - Name: B
      source: [a, b, c, a, b, c]
      dest: [x, y, z, x, y, z]
```

Iterate the list and filter the items, e.g.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      out: "{{ out|d([]) + [{'Name': item.Name,
                             'source': _src,
                             'dest': _dst}] }}"
    loop: "{{ output }}"
    vars:
      _src: "{{ item.source|unique }}"
      _dst: "{{ item.dest|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  out:
    - Name: A
      dest: [x, y, z]
      source: [a, b, c]
    - Name: B
      dest: [x, y, z]
      source: [a, b, c]
```