# Getting error Object of type set is not JSON serializable while executing my ansible script

Tags: list, ansible, unique, json-query

My scenario is a bit similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042014/how-to-remove-duplicate-elements-whem-the-dict-key-value-is-a-list)

but a bit difference, let me take same example mentioned  in above question solution by Vladimir Botka ,  added name:c and name:d block

```
output:
- Name: A
  source: [a, b, c, a, b, c]
  dest: [x,y,z]
- Name: B
  source: [a, b, c, a, b, c]
  dest: [x.c, y, z, x, y, z]
- Name: C
  source:
  dest:      
- Name: D
  source: "1.2"
  dest: "x"
```

I am using same answer suggested in above post but a bit modifications as :

```
- set_fact:
    out1: "{{output |replace('None','[]')}}"
- set_fact:
    out: "{{ out|d([]) + [{'Name': item.Name,
                           'source': _src,
                           'dest': _dst}] }}"
  loop: "{{ out1 }}"
  vars:
    _src: "{{ item.source|unique}}"
    _dst: "{{ item.dest|unique}}"
- debug:
      var: out
```

I used `out1: "{{output |replace('None','[]')}}"` cause loop is failing for `name:c` as source and dest is empty and not a list i am making it list by replacing `None` as `[]`, to over come loop error, i am able to fix loop error.
not sure if its right approach or not but solved loop error issue.

but second error i am getting is `Object of type set is not JSON serializable` for `name:d` cause source and destination is not a list.

how can this error be fixed or any workaround ??

Comment: Hi nauto welcome to SO. I can't reproduce your error, but I'd bet it's that `| unique` is producing a `set` type in python, so adding `| list` should fold it over to a `list` type: thus: `_src: "{{ item.source | unique | list }}"`

Comment: @mdaniel tried your suggestion but in the debug i see :`"source": [  ".", "2","1" ]` which is not what i want , when i changed my vars like source:["1.2"] , maually added square brackets then in the debug i do see source:["1.2"]. but unfortunately my vars are dynamic some are list and some are just dict key:value so i can't manually change make them in square brackets [ ] . also its interesting that you can't reproduce on your side. my ansible version is `ansible 2.10.3`

Comment: Right, I appreciate you didn't get the end result you wanted because you're mangling the hell out of your variables, but your question was "type set is not serializable" -- did the `|list` coercion fix that error or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Error when source and destination is not a list**"*

A: Filter *unique* items if the type of the value is a list otherwise copy the value, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        out: "{{ out|d([]) + [{'Name': item.Name,
                               'source': _src,
                               'dest': _dst}] }}"
      loop: "{{ out1 }}"
      vars:
        _src: "{{ (item.source|type_debug == 'list')|
                  ternary(item.source|unique, item.source) }}"
        _dst: "{{ (item.dest|type_debug == 'list')|
                  ternary(item.dest|unique, item.dest) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, i am impressed the way you think and code. 
Wish one day i can do like you.